# LibreOffice stopped working with Ubuntu 18

Tags: 18.04, libreoffice

LibreOffice stopped working since I upgraded to Ubuntu 18.
It complains about "out of memory" error when I start it. My computer has 24Gb RAM so I don't see how it require more to run....

Command line:

```
$ soffice 
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
JavaVM: JNI_CreateJavaVM called os::abort(), caught by abort_handler 
in javavm.cxx
[Java framework] sunjavaplugin.soCan not create JavaVirtualMachine, 
abort handler was called.

$ free
          total       utilisé      libre     partagé tamp/cache   disponible
Mem:       24113928     9915852     2726308     1619792    11471768    
12208684
Partition d'échange:    34576376       75516    34500860
```

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling libreoffice?  `sudo apt install --reinstall libreoffice`

Comment: I just reinstalled, however libreoffice is still unstable, sometime it starts, then freezes. Sometime it shut down unexpectedly and complains about insufficient memory while my system has more than enough, and is able to run several virtual machines at once very smoothly....

Answer (score 1):

After update of my Ubuntu 18.04.1 LibreOffice would not not start. I tried suggested solutions like deleting libreoffice from .config, uninstalling and installing LibreOffice, etc. Nothing worked. Then I tried Terrance's reinstall (`sudo apt install --reinstall libreoffice`) and it worked.